# How do I handle an exception thrown by a COM library from a worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, com

I am building a .Net application which is using a COM library (I am really bad at COM, but its a library which I need to register using `regsvr32` and once referenced in visual studio it says the file type is ActiveX).

In a console application, I am creating a new COM object like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var comObj = new EikonDesktopDataAPI();
    comObj.OnStatusChanged += EikonDesktopDataApi_OnStatusChanged;
    comObj.Initialize();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void EikonDesktopDataApi_OnStatusChanged(EEikonStatus status)
{
    try{
        throw new Exception("An exception 1.");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("Tell the main thread." , ex);
    }
}
```

So the application initialise the Api synchronously on the Main thread and wait on `Console.ReadLine()`. After a few seconds the `EikonDesktopDataApi_OnStatusChanged` event is triggered. When debugging, I can see that this is handled on a worker thread. As the exception is thrown on another thread, the console application doesn't crash. How can I catch this exception?

I tried to add the `SLAThreadAttribute` on the Main method, but this cause the event to never be raised.

I also tried to use :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

But the exception is not handled neither.

The only way I found to "catch" the exception was to use :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
```

But this cause the handler method to handle 3 exceptions: `"An exception 1"`, then `"Tell the main thread."` and finally a `"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"`. Which means I will handle even "caught" exception which is impractical.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I did a WPF application, where I am instantiating the COM object from the main thread. Once initialized the event is raised and my event handler runs on the MAIN thread, but if I throw an exception, it wont crash the application or raise an `Unhandledexception` event. I really don't understand why exceptions thrown on the main thread just does nothing.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. An object (COM or not) cannot throw exceptions from inside your own event handler - you own the code in the handler, not the object. Where would the real exception be coming from? In any case: no, exceptions cannot cross threads, period. And in practice, an exception thrown inside that event handler **must** be handled in the event handler itself (you don't own any of the code above the handler in the call stack).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that. So what would be the correct way to tell the main thread that there is a problem ? Thanks

Comment: What you observed is quite normal, COM does not allow exceptions to cross a language barrier.  Pretty necessary, exceptions are a language runtime implementation detail.  So the CLR will always catch any exception you throw and turn it into an HRESULT error code, passed back to the COM server.  What it does with that error is entirely up to that server.  And sure, do expect nothing at all, raising an event is generally treated as a "best effort".  Nothing you can do to change it.  You can call the COM dev but do expect a "don't do that" answer.